# ConstraintLayout goneMargin not working when centered to an edge

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

[image]

For the above layout that I have declared in the XML below, I am trying to have the start margin for `view_2` to default to say `12dp` when `view_1` is `GONE`. Wondering how do I achieve it using `goneMargin*`? Setting `app:layout_goneMarginStart="12dp"` on `view_2` is not working when I have the constraints that act like opposite forces pulling the widget apart equally ([I am referring to this approach of positioning](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#CenteringPositioning))

```xml
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:background="@color/faded_green"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </View>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_2"
        android:background="@color/deep_red"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_1">
    </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to programmatically remove the end constraint on *view_2*. You may also want to remove the bottom constraint on *view_2* as well. Here is an example that has a *gone* margin of `12dp` for the start and top of *view_2*.

(`app:layout_goneMarginStart="12dp"` doesn't work but `app:layout_goneMarginLeft="12dp"` does. I am using *ConstraintLayout 1.1.3*. Maybe this is fixed in a later release.)

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ConstraintLayout layout;
    private View view1;
    int margin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        view1 = findViewById(R.id.view_1);
        margin = (int) (12 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
        cs.clone(layout);

        if (view1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            cs.setVisibility(R.id.view_1, View.GONE);
            cs.clear(R.id.view_2, ConstraintSet.END);
            cs.clear(R.id.view_2, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        } else {
            cs.setVisibility(R.id.view_1, View.VISIBLE);
            cs.connect(R.id.view_2, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.view_1, ConstraintSet.END);
            cs.connect(R.id.view_2, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.view_1, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        }
        cs.applyTo(layout);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/faded_green"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/deep_red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view_1"
        app:layout_goneMarginLeft="12dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="12dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Toggle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the reply... I am marking this as a valid answer.

Comment: It was `app:layout_goneMarginLeft="12dp"` that I was looking for! app:layout_goneMarginStart="12dp" was not working, but app:layout_goneMarginLeft="12dp" worked it looks like! Thanks again!